# How to trim/delete first minute from beginning/end of a .wav recording in android

Tags: android, audio

Im trying to delete a part of my .wav file I just recorded, Thing is Im aware that a wav file contains 44 bytes of header data but I want to know how to trim minutes from the beginning of my recorded .wav file, Any answers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance,
below is my sample code of when I tried to delete like 10 seconds (assuming its 100000 bytes)

```
     byte fileContent[]= new byte[(int)inputFile.length()];
       try {
        fis.read(fileContent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }// Reads the file content as byte from the list.
        /* copy the entire file, but not the first 6 bytes */
        byte[] headerlessFileContent = new byte[fileContent.length-1000000];
        for(int j=1000000; j<fileContent.length;j++){
            headerlessFileContent[j-1000000] = fileContent[j];
        }
        fileContent = headerlessFileContent;
        /* Write the byte into the combine file. */
        try {
    fos.write (fileContent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "End!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    }
```

Comment: **"below is my sample code of when I tried to delete like 10 seconds"** - OK...so what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Nothing happened. Not even a slight delay, It was supposed to work like that right? Probably I was just deleting data from the header and not from the file itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does logcat show? Also, I just noticed this you say in the question **"assuming its 100000 bytes"** (one hundred thousand) but you're using 1000000 (one million) in the code.

Comment: I seek correct code.not typos

Comment: The only reason I pointed out the typo is very often problems here on stackoverflow can simply come down to typos in code. It wasn't clear from your question if you wanted to trim 100000 or 1000000 bytes. Most importantly, as I said in my previous comment, post the logcat output - if, as you say, there isn't even a slight delay, it suggests an exception is being thrown and immediately causing one of the catch blocks to execute. You might also want to Google the WAV format because you'll not only need to save the header but re-write it as Dan Ritchie states in his answer.

Comment: Are you 100% positive Im only supposed to delete bytes for like 30 seconds to be trimmed. have you done something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the 44-byte header as well as 999956 bytes of the audio portion.  What you need to do is:

1. Copy the 44-byte header from the old file to a new file
2. Copy from the old file to the new file, starting at position 10000044 (the end of the header plus 10 seconds).

This advice assumes that the header does not contain the length of the file!  If it does, then you must find out the format of the header, and also rewrite the header with the correct length of the new file

Comment: After doing that, all I get is a faster sound but no audio trimmed